# Subscription has received a request for an abort shutdown

Tags: ibm-data-replication

I have a subscription with DB2 for i (as400) as source and Kafka as target (11.4.0.2). The replication method is REFRESH.

There was a table in the subscription, which was running well.

But after I delete it and add it to another new subscription (with same source and target, also REFRESH), it cannot be replicated. The replication end with following message:
`Subscription XXX has received a request for an abort shutdown.` There are no other error messages. The table mapping (flag for refresh already) seems being ignored by CDC.

From the log, it returns:
`Received normal shutdown request number 9 with reason OTHER_ENGINE_COMPLETE`

I have no idea what is happening as there are no obvious hints from logs.

I tried (1) recreate table mapping and (2) update table definitions, but not working.
Other tables in the subscription can be replicated.

Answer (score 0):

Please check after you delete table mapping from earlier subscription, is it still showing by checking 'replication tables' in MC (select datastore -> replication tables) select and remove and remap in new subscription.

Thanks
Sudarshan K

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I'm not sure what does that mean. Btw the earlier subscription has been deleted.